# Почему в tkinter размывается интерфейс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**Проблема такая:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интерфейс, в том числе кнопки, флажки, галочки и т.д. РАЗМЫВАЕТСЯ, когда я просто запускаю файл или через pycharm. А вот как это выглядит в Thonny.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ничего не размывается!

Если что то код такой:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
ttk.Button(root, text='Кнопа!').pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Код везде одинаковый.  Python 3.8.2, Windows 10

Как сделать так чтобы он всегда не размывался?

Comment: может у вас 'стиль' такой ? поробуйте tk вместо ttk в кнопке

Comment: Это похоже на "кривое" масштабирование содержимого окна операционной системой. Возможно влияет дробное масштабирование графического интерфейса (типа x1.25), но это не точно.

Answer (score 0):

Как сказали в комментариях, лучше использовать обычный Tkinter.

Попробуйте это:

```
from tkinter import * # импортируем Tkinter;
root = Tk() # создаём окно;
btn = Button(root, text='Кнопа!') # создаём кнопку
btn.pack() #;
root.mainloop()
```